# How to create dynamic ng-model bindings , using dynamic templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

so following is my Dynamically created template, it has an issue, when i add my template, it brings values from the previous DOM. Where was i want new to be empty.

Following is my HTML file, and `my-custom-row-template` is where i am repeating my template, now i assume that `$index` will create a new index, and values/DOM wouldn't repeat.

```
<section class="main_container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form ng-submit="addNew()">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()"/></th>
                                            <th scope="col">Setup Responses</th>
                                            <th>Add Condition</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
                                            <td scope="col">
                                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="personalDetail.selected"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td scope="col" class="col-xs-10">

                                                <div ng-repeat="condition_set in conditions track by $index" my-custom-row-template></div>
                                            </td>
                                            </td>
                                            <td scope="col">

                                                <input type="button" value="Add Condition" ng-click="addCondition()"
                                                       class="btn btn-primary addnew"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input ng-hide="!personalDetails.length" type="button"
                                               class="btn btn-danger pull-right"
                                               ng-click="remove()" value="Remove">
                                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" value="Add New" ng-click="addNew()">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Save">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </span>
```

And this is my template code

```
<div class="col-xs-8 pull-left">
    <div class="row form-group">
        <!--<select ng-model="response.condition" style="color: black;">-->
        <!--<option>Response Message</option>-->
        <!--<option>IF</option>-->
        <!--<option>Else</option>-->
        <!--</select>-->
        <select ng-model="selectedCondition[$index]">
            <option ng-repeat="x in conditions.condition_set" value="{{x.name}}">{{x.value}}</option>
        </select>

        <input ng-show="selectedCondition=='0'" type="text" class="form-control"
               ng-model="personalDetail[$index].message"/>
        <input ng-show="selectedCondition=='1'" type="text" class="form-control"
               ng-model="conditions[$index].response"/>
        <input ng-show="selectedCondition=='2'" type="text" class="form-control"
               ng-model="conditions[$index].elseMessage"/>
        <select ng-show="selectedCondition=='1'" ng-model="goToStepOrNew">
            <option ng-repeat="x in conditions[$index].create_new_conditions" value="{{x.name}}">{{x.value}}</option>
        </select>

        <input type="button" value="Remove Condition" ng-click="remove_condition($index)" class="btn btn-danger"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

And this is how i am handling it within my controller

```
$http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "team_lead_showed_contacts/ajax",
                data: $.param(obj),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
                transformResponse: [function (data) {
                    var str = '';
                    str = data.toString();
                    str = str.replace(/\\/g, 0);
                    return str;
                }]
            }).then(function (response) {
                //debugger;

                $scope.campaigns = JSON.parse(response.data);
                $scope.personalDetails = [
                    {
                        'add_tempalte': '<div my-custom-row-template> </div>',
                    }
                ];

                $scope.addNew = function (personalDetail) {
                    $scope.personalDetails.push({
                        'add_template': '<div my-custom-row-template> </div>',
                    });
                };


                function triggerNewRow($scope) {
                    if ($scope.goToStepOrNew == 0) {

                    }
                }

                $scope.remove = function () {
                    var newDataList = [];
                    $scope.selectedAll = false;
                    angular.forEach($scope.personalDetails, function (selected) {
                        if (!selected.selected) {
                            newDataList.push(selected);
                        }
                    });
                    $scope.personalDetails = newDataList;
                };

                $scope.checkAll = function () {
                    if (!$scope.selectedAll) {
                        $scope.selectedAll = true;
                    } else {
                        $scope.selectedAll = false;
                    }
                    angular.forEach($scope.personalDetails, function (personalDetail) {
                        personalDetail.selected = $scope.selectedAll;
                    });
                };


                $scope.conditions = [];
                $scope.conditions.push('myCustomRowTemplate');
                $index = 0;
                $scope.addCondition = function () {
                    $scope.conditions.push('myCustomRowTemplate');
                };
                $scope.conditions.condition_set = [
                    {name: 0, value: 'Response Message'},
                    {name: 1, value: 'IF'},
                    {name: 2, value: "ELSE"}
                ];
                $scope.conditions.create_new_conditions = [
                    {name: 0, value: 'Create Step'},
                ];
                $scope.remove_condition = function (element) {
                    $scope.conditions.splice(element, 1);
                    // console.log(element);
                };

            });
```

For Reference i am attaching an image to give an idea, to what happens when i copy Add New. Copy of already present Elements is pushed into the DOM.
[image: Check Image to see duplication of content.]

**EDIT**
Tried some thing like this following [Kinda same issue like this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813862/ng-repeat-with-empty-objects?rq=1)
but no effect.

```
$scope.personalDetails = [
                        {
                            'add_template': '<div my-custom-row-template> </div>',
                        }
                    ];
                    var newStep = angular.copy($scope.personalDetails);
                    $scope.addNew = function (personalDetail) {

                        $scope.personalDetails.push(
                            newStep
                        );
                    };
```

Comment: Somethings in the template don't look right, is selectedCondition an array? You access it like selectedCondition[$index], and then use selectedCondition == '1' as a condition check. I'm not sure that makes sense...

Comment: yes this isnt correct infact [$index] used here dosent reflect any change, but i simulated it here to give an idea as what i actually want, i just want my DOM to be dynamic.

Comment: The directive is reflecting the $scope values from the controller because by default that is how the $scope is inherited. Take a look at this particular link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope-in-angularjs

Comment: @Stradosphere: so what you are referring to is actually change in scope?

Comment: You can either have your directive inherit the $scope which is default and the data will be the same, or you can have the directive use isolated $scope so each instance has its own copy, which I think it what you are trying to do. But I don't see your directive above...

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Minimal** – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem, See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @georgeawg: i agree to this, and i also follow same practice, but on similar question that i asked, i was asked to put more code, and after number of comments i was told now it makes sense. Other then that i totally endorse your point here

Comment: **Divide and conquer**. When you have a small amount of code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back.